# How to configure the TypeORM module in NestJS without 'process.env' and values unknown at advance?

Tags: node.js, class, nestjs, decorator

Typical example of the configuration of `TypeOrmModule` via decorator:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [],
      autoLoadEntities: true, // Must be only on local development mode
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

All settings has been hardcoded. What if we don't know *at advance* the `host`, `port`, environment name on which `autoLoadEntities` flag depends etc.? "At advance" means "when the static fields and values inside decorators has been resolved, but of course, the picking up of all configuration will done before `await NestFactory.create()`.

```
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import type { NestExpressApplication } from "@nestjs/platform-express";
import Path from "path";
import { Logger } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";
import { ConsoleCommandsParser } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-nodejs";


(async function runApplication(): Promise<void> {

  const configurationFromConsoleCommand: ConsoleCommandsParser.ParsedCommand<ConsoleLineInterface.ParsedArguments> =
      ConsoleCommandsParser.parse(process.argv, ConsoleLineInterface.specification);

  const normalizedConfiguration: NormalizedConfiguration = ConfigurationNormalizer.normalize({
    configurationFromConsoleCommand
  });

  ConfigurationRepresentative.initialize(normalizedConfiguration);

  // The preparing of the configuration is complete

  const nestJS_Application: NestExpressApplication =
      await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(NestJS_ApplicationRootModule);

  await nestJS_Application.listen(normalizedConfiguration.HTTP_Port);

})().

    catch((error: unknown): void => {
      Logger.logError({
        errorType: "ServerStartingFailedError",
        title: "Server starting failed",
        description: "The error occurred during starting of server",
        occurrenceLocation: "runApplication()",
        caughtError: error
      });
    });
```

One way is a usage of environment variables (`process.env.XXX`). However it violates the condition "unknown at advance" and must NOT be the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
```

**these properties can not be undefined or unknown you must configure them first**

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        port: configService.get<number>('DATABASE_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DATABASE_USER'),
        password: configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DATABASE_DB'),
        schema: configService.get('DATABASE_SCHEMA'),
        synchronize: !!configService.get<boolean>('DATABASE_SYNCRONIZE'),
        logging: false, //!!configService.get<boolean>('DATABASE_LOGGING'),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand that these properties are required. The topic is how to configure them without `process.env`. As I wrote in the question field, "At advance" means "when the static fields and values inside decorators has been resolved, but of course, the picking up of all configuration will done before `await NestFactory.create()`. It must be some way besides the usage of `process.env`. Would you please to update your answer?

Comment: check if it works to you.

Comment: Works fine! You deserved the prize, your reputation has doubled.